# How to pass extra argument to get_serializer_class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to select a serializer based on the value of an object instance. How do I pass an additional argument to get_serializer_class to be able to do the validation there?

```
def get_serializer_class(self, extra_option):
        if extra_option:
            return ModelSerializer
        return ModelSerializer2
```

```
serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, extra_option=smth_instance)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_option'
```

If I make a custom class then serializer selection works... maybe this is legit workaround?

```
 def choose_serializer(self, product, data):
        if product.document.type == 1:
            return Serializer1(product, data=data)
        elif product.document.type == 2:
            return Serializer2(product, data=data)
```

```
serializer = self.choose_serializer(data=request.data, product=product)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier to check the action to decide what serializer to use. Ex.

```py
def get_serializer_class(self):
  if self.action == "retrieve":
    return ModelOutputSerializer
  else:
    return ModelDefaultSerializer
```

Otherwise you likely need to override the action you want the different kwarg on and pass that down, overriding the necessary methods as you go. Ex.

```py
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  instance = self.get_object()
  serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, extra_option=...)
  return Response(serializer.data)

def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
  serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
  kwargs.setdefault('context', self.get_serializer_context())
  return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
  if kwargs.pop("extra_option", None):
    return ExtraOptionSerializer
  else:     
    return super().get_serializer_class()
```

Also check out classy DRF for reference: https://www.cdrf.co/3.13/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#retrieve.

Edit: also `self.serializer_class` defaults to whatever you define on the view set so you likely want to instead call `self.get_serializer_class(...)` like you did with your custom method above.